# Make AIR swf resolution independent on Android

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, mobile, air

with the Flash IDE, I must create an AIR project for Android mobile devices (NOT tablets): my problem is that I would like to make it resolution-independent. Android-equipped mobile devices are many and they may have different screen dimensions.

So, first of all, I would like to know if I must choose a particular stage dimension in my Flash project. Secondly, I would like to know how to adapt the content to the screen resolution and if it has any drawbacks (stretching, etc.) that can damage the appearence of the app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lash stage dimensions and content dimensions can be separated.

When you are using ( at the start of your application ):

```
stage.scale = StageScale.NO_SCALE;
```

you are able to separate the content size from the stage size. But then you will be needing to do the resize by your self depending on the `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight` parameters.

Comment: make sure you listen to `stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResize);` so you know when to reposition your items

Comment: If he is making the stuff for a mobile device, i think there will be no `stageResize` events.

Comment: Yes, Android send resize events. One at the beggining, and resize event every time screen rotates. You also get resize events when lock screen appears, because Android switches to portrait mode to display lock screen, if you're in landscape mode. Yes, even if you set noAutoRotate in app.xml. It then switches back to landscape after the user unlocks the phone.